# Derivative of continuous multilinear maps

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Suppose, $E_1,\dots, E_n$, $F$ are are complete normed linear spaces(Banach spaces). Suppose $f:E_1\times\dots\times E_n\to F$ be a continuous multilinear map. I need to find its derivative $Df(x)(h)$, with $x,h \in E_1\times\dots\times E_n$.

I tried expanding $f(x_1+h_1,\dots, x_n+h_n)$ for $n=3$ and I got $\displaystyle f(x_1+h_1,\dots, x_n+h_n)=\sum_{\pi_i\in \{x_i,h_i\}}f(\pi_1,\dots,\pi_n)$. So, my guess is that $Df(x)(h)$ is $\displaystyle \sum_{\pi_i\in \{x_i,h_i\}}f(\pi_1,\dots,\pi_n)-f(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ and so I need to show that $f(h_1,\dots,h_n)=o(||(h_1,\dots,h_n)||)$ but I am not sure how to prove it.

I tried using the max norm i.e. suppose $||(h_1,\dots,h_n)||=||h_k||$ which means $\displaystyle f(h_1,\dots,h_n)/||(h_1,\dots,h_n)||=f(h_1,\dots,\frac{h_k}{||h_k||},\dots,h_n)$ but I don't know how to proceed further.
Thanks.

Comment: A side comment: A complete normed space is called a Banach space; so you can abbreviate your first line. :)

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**. Note that for a multilinear $f$ being continuous is equivalent to being bounded, that is, we have 
$$ \|f(x_1, \ldots, x_n)\| \le C\|x_1\|\cdots \|x_n\| $$
for some constant $C$. Now $f(\pi_1, \ldots, \pi_n)$ is $o(\|h\|)$ for $h\to 0$, iff at least two of the $\pi_i = h_i$. And that's good, because 
$$ f(h_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n) + f(x_1, h_2, x_3, \ldots, x_n) + \cdots + f(x_1, \ldots, x_{n-1}, h_n) $$
is linear in $h$ (and $\sum f(\pi_1, \ldots, \pi_n) - f(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ is not).

Comment: $f(\pi_1, \ldots, \pi_n)$ is $o(\|h\|)$ for $h\to 0$, iff at least two of the $\pi_i = h_i$. I am not sure I follow.